# 1:1 relationship in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship

I need 1:1 relationship between `ApplicationUser` and my own class in entity framework.

I do this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

    /*Realations*/

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual Posts Post { get; set; }
}


public class Posts : System.Object
{
    public Posts()
    {
        this.PostDate = DateTime.Now;
        this.PostViews = 0;
        this.PostPic = "d.jpg";
    }

    [Key]
    public int PostID { get; set; }

    public string PostName { get; set; }
    public string PostSummery { get; set; }
    public string PostDesc { get; set; }
    public string PostPic { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    public int PostViews { get; set; }
    public string postMetaKeys { get; set; }
    public string PostMetaDesc { get; set; }


    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }


    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Categories Category { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> commnets {get; set;}
}
```

But I am getting an exception when I write the command "add-migration relation" inside `Nuget` console.

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'FinalKaminet.Models.ApplicationUser' and 'Models.Posts'. The
>   principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using
>   either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

I also add below code inside `IdentityModels`, but another error was shown:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 


        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasOptional(f => f.Post)
        .WithRequired(s => s.ApplicationUser);
    }
```

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> ApplicationUser_Post_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'ApplicationUser_Post_Target' in relationship 'ApplicationUser_Post'.
>   Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the
>   upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

What is wrong?

Comment: what is shown *another error*?

Comment: @AdilMammadov, Updated question.

Comment: As I remember `IdentityUser` has `string` key. Can it be the problem?

Comment: I declare the `FK` as string,too. `public string UserId { get; set; }`

Comment: where do you need to create `1:1` relationship ? `ApplicationUser : Posts` ? why you have used wrong naming for the `Post` ? class name should be the singular.collections should be plural. like this ` public virtual Post Posts { get; set; }`.but that thing is just a side note.note related to your issue.hope you'll give a feedback for this.

Comment: First of all, I do not see this property in your question. Secondly, in *one-to-one* relationship there is no *FK*. *PK* in the dependent is also *FK* to principal.

Comment: Thank you @Sampath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want a 1 to 1 relation between user and post ? A user can only post one, and only, post ?

Anyway, in EF (at least 6) a 1 to 1 relation can be established between two entities sharing the same PK. That is the PK is the FK. So you must set the PK of `posts` as a string.

Otherwise you are in a 1 to * relation.

Comment: Correct. It's sort of possible to use FK 1 to 1 association, but, only if it is unidirectional. Reference: [Shared Primary Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations) vs [One-to-One Foreign Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations).

Answer (score 0):

Add `[Required]` attribute to `UserId` property in `Posts` class.

By default, a string property would be nullable but as this is the foreign key and you want the relationship to be Required, you'll have to set the `UserId` property as not-nullable which can be done by adding `[Required]` attribute.

Comment: When I add `[Required]` to `UserId` I getting the second error.