# EF6 one to one fluent API configuration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am struggling to map my EF6 classes to table structure. Here is my table structure:

```
**TableA:**
Id (PK),
Name,
BId (FK to TableB), NULLABLE
```

---

```
**TableB:**
Id (PK),
Prop1,
Prop2
```

---

My classes are:

```
class TableA
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
    int BId;

    TableB bObject;
}

//TableB doesnt need to know about TableA
class TableB
{
    int Id;
    string prop1;
    string prop2;
}
```

I want to use a configuration for TableA to something like:

```
HasRequired(a => a.bObject).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(a => a.BId);
```

However, this is not working. How do I fix this?

Thanks
Vik

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1:1 relationship in Entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484566/11-relationship-in-entity-framework)

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx